# How would I connect a 4 pin sound sensor to a raspberry pi?

Tags: connectors

I have a 4 pin sound sensor like this:
[image: example picture of my sound sensor with the name of the pins it attaches to.]

How would I connect it to my Raspberry Pi with only wires?

Answer (score 0):

It has two outputs.  One digital and one analogue.

To use the analogue output you will need to connect it to an ADC and then connect the ADC to the Pi.

To use the digital output you can connect it directly to a GPIO if you power the device from 3V3.  If you power the device from 5V you will need to connect the output to a voltage divider and connect the output of the voltage divider to the GPIO.  The digital output signals if the sound is currently louder than the preset threshold set by the adjustment screw.

Answer (score 0):

All four pins can be connected with wire.

digital signal = GPIO 24 [Pin 18 (RPi)]
+V             = 3,3V [Pin 1 (RPi)]
GND            = GND [Pin 06 (RPi)]
analog signal  = Analog 0
[Pin A0 (ADS1115 - KY-053)]
[image]

I have attached the schematic, hopefully this helps.
The sensor has 3 main components on its circuit board. First, the sensor unit at the front of the module
which measures the area physically and sends an analog signal to the second unit, the amplifier. The amplifier amplifies the signal, according to the resistant value of the potentiometer, and sends the signal to
the analog output of the module. The third component is a comparator which switches the digital out and the LED if the signal falls under a
specific value. You can control the sensitivity by adjusting the potentiometer. The signal will be inverted; that means that if you measure a high value, it Please notice: is shown as a low voltage value at the analog output.